# Structuring async networking code in controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

I've just recently switched from ASIHttpRequest library to AFNetworking. I really like the simplicity, but I am still struggling to understand how to structure my async code.

Please consider this sign up scenario.

- First I want to check if the entered email adresse is available.
- Next I want to check if the entered username is available.
- If both the above is valid and available I want to submit my real signup request.

My code would be looking something like.

```
- (void)signUp{

    BOOL hasValidEmail = [self validateEmail:email];
    BOOL hasValidUsername = [self validateUsername:username];

    if(!hasValidEmail){
        NSLog(@"Invalid email");
        return;
    }

    if(!hasValidUsername){
        NSLog(@"Invalid username");
        return;
    }

    if (hasValidEmail && hasValidUsername) {
        NSLog(@"Go ahead and create account");
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to structure this considering the async nature of my networking methods. Often last condition will be reached before the two previous availability checks have received their response.

The availability checking methods would look something like:

```
- (BOOL)validateEmail:(NSString*)email{

    __block NSString* emailAlreadyExists = @"";

    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user/emailexists/%@", email];

    [[APIClient sharedClient] getPath:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        emailAlreadyExists = [responseObject valueForKey:@"exists"];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError* error) {
        NSLog(@"Email availability check failed: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];

    if([emailAlreadyExists isEqualToString:@"true"]){
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;   
}
```

Maybe it's just my blocks skills that needs improving, but I'd really like to hear how you would you structure a scenario like this?

Though code samples would be "nice", I'm really looking for patterns or good techniques you know of.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually break these things into steps and start the next step when the previous one succeeds. Blocks are great to pass along for this purpose.

This obviously wont compile, but hopefully it can give you some idea of how to do this:

```
typedef enum
{
    SignupErrorNetworkError,
    SignupErrorEmailAlreadyTaken,
    SignupErrorUsernameAlreadyTaken,
} SignupError;

typedef enum
{
    // These steps must be performed in this order.
    SignupStepValidateEmail,
    SignupStepValidateUsername,
    SignupStepCreateAccount,
} SignupStep;

typedef void (^SignupSuccessBlock)();
typedef void (^SignupFailureBlock)(SignupError reason);

// Call this to sign up.
- (void)signupWithSuccess:(SignupSuccessBlock)success failure:(SignupFailureBlock)failure
{
    // Start the first step of the process.
    [self performSignupStep:SignupStepValidateEmail success:success failure:failure];
}

// Internal method. Don't call this from outside.
- (void)performSignupStep:(SignupStep)step success:(SignupSuccessBlock)success failure:(SignupFailureBlock)failure
{
    switch (step)
    {
        case SignupStepValidateEmail:
            [[APIClient sharedClient] getPath:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                if ([responseObject valueForKey:@"exists"])
                {
                    if (failure) failure(SignupErrorEmailAlreadyTaken);
                    return;                }
                }
                // Start next async step in signup process.
                [self performSignupStep:SignupStepValidateUsername success:success failure:failure];
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError* error) {
                if (failure) failure(SignupErrorNetworkError);
            }];
            break;
        case SignupStepValidateUsername:
            // Similar to the step above. Starts the create account step on success.
            break;            
        case SignupStepCreateAccount:
            // Similar to the step above. Call the success block when done.
            break;            
    }
}
```

If the switch is getting too long and ugly you could also make the steps into separate methods and delete the step-enum: `validateEmailWithSuccess:failure` which continues by calling `validateUsernameWithSuccess:failure` etc.

I just wanted to emphasize the state machine nature of the process in the example above.

Comment: This was exactly the kind of setup I was looking for. Indeed I do need to read up on blocks. Thank you.